# When compiling cpp-code wihtin R making use of the Gnu Scientific Library via RcppGSL, inclusion of some GSL-header files produce errors

Tags: r, rcpp, gsl

I got a problem with the compilation of c++ code within R using the RcppGSL package. I'm on Unix (Ubuntu 13.10, Installed in an Oracle VM VirtualBox; R-version 3.0.2). I managed to install everything necessary for the compilation of code making use of the GSL library (at least I think so). The following code is no problem:

```
library(RcppGSL)
library(inline)

code <- ' 
#include<gsl/gsl_vector.h>
//#include<gsl/gsl_pow_int.h>

RcppGSL::vector<double> v(1);
v[0] = 1.23;
double ret = v[0];
v.free() ;
return(Rcpp::wrap(ret));
' 
foo <- cxxfunction(signature(), code, plugin = "RcppGSL", verbose = T)
```

This compiles nicely, the function returns 1.23 as expected.
But as soon as I include other header files than gsl_vector.h or gsl_matrix.h (like in the upper example when gsl/gsl_pow_int.h is not commented out on line 6), I get following error message:

```
Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created! In file included from file196520f2906c.cpp:32:0:
/usr/include/gsl/gsl_pow_int.h: In function ‘SEXPREC* file196520f2906c()’:
/usr/include/gsl/gsl_pow_int.h:34:1: error: expected unqualified-id before string constant
 __BEGIN_DECLS
 ^
make: *** [file196520f2906c.o] Error 1
```

I have no clue what's the matter. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you just had some basic errors here. The following variant works fine:

```
#include<RcppGSL.h>
#include<gsl/gsl_vector.h>
#include<gsl/gsl_pow_int.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppGSL)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double foo(int ignored) {
    RcppGSL::vector<double> v(1);
    v[0] = 1.23;
    double ret = v[0];
    v.free() ;
    return ret;
}
```

as per a quick test:

```
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/so2.cpp")
R> foo(3)
[1] 1.23
R>
```

There are examples: a simple but complete package (using a vector norm) is included
in the RcppGSL package itself; there are also posts on the Rcpp Gallery.

And generally speaking, including our header `RcppGSL.h` already pulls in the GSL headers
for vectors and matrices so if you include them again (which none of our examples do) you may indeed get a error -- there has to be a certain order to make the template magic work.